# How do I parse this JSON data and get the attributes I want as a list?

Tags: json, actionscript-3

I am building an air app that needs to access data from Firebase Database using the REST API. I am able to get the data but I do not know how to get the information I need from that data.

Basically, I have an Android app and a Desktop app. The android app uploads/Modifies data and the Desktop app needs to access that data and send signals to the ESP8266 via a socket connection. I have a list of 'Lights' each light as a 'lightname', 'status' and 'pin'. I want to be able to loop through all the 'pin's.

When I try to get the data , I get this JSON:

```
{"-LAb_YKS9l7qQno25AY5":{"lightname":"light1","pin":"14","status":"on","timestamp":1524303808146},"-LAb_cRpsGpQfr7JbCfI":{"lightname":"light2","pin":"15","status":"on","timestamp":1524303830159},"-LAb_zbf2sYuyTtW_uEr":{"lightname":"blah","pin":"9","status":"on","timestamp":1524303921921},"-LAba68lzyG15n6anuSF":{"lightname":"dishl","pin":"7","status":"on","timestamp":1524303955946},"-LAdZW2JjQVGfLMc_sb4":{"lightname":"cxcxc","pin":"14","status":"on","timestamp":1524337092712}}
```

I want to loop through all the lights and access their 'pin' values.
Here is what i've tried:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < e.target.data.length; i++)
        {
            trace(e.target.data[i]["status"]);
        }
```

I get this error:

```
Property 0 not found on String and there is no default value.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the **e.target.data** answer you get from Firebase is a **String** and first you need to **JSON.parse(...)** it to transform it into data. Then your data is not an **Array**, it is an **Object**. You loop through it as following:

```
// Parse the incoming data.
var aData:Object = JSON.parse(e.target.data);

// Loop through string keys of the data object.
for (var aKey:String in aData)
{
    trace("");
    trace(aKey);

    // Assign entry reference to another local variable. This is not 
    // mandatory, but the following code is shorter and thus more readable.
    var anEntry:Object = aData[aKey];

    trace(anEntry['pin']);
    trace(anEntry['status']);
    trace(anEntry['lightname']);
}
```

If you have no use of key values, you might do it in a slightly different way:

```
// Parse the incoming data.
var aData:Object = JSON.parse(e.target.data);

// Loop through values of the data object while ignoring the keys.
for each (var anEntry:Object in aData)
{
    trace("");

    trace(anEntry['pin']);
    trace(anEntry['status']);
    trace(anEntry['lightname']);
}
```

Comment: I tried this just now but it never goes inside the loop.

Comment: @DanishAjaib Ah, you never parsed it. The point is, your data is a **String** and you need to **JSON.parse(...)** it first to transform it into data you will be able to work with.